# Lync 2013 no audio device without webcam

Tags: audio, hdmi, webcam, lync-2013, logitech-webcam

Hope someone has a solution to this.

Let me describe the issue, I work at a company where we have Cisco MX300 G2 meeting room screens, those screens has built in speakers and works fine with the connected pc through HDMI cable and plays sound if you visit youtube, if you look at the attached screenshot (cant post yet) you will see that the device is listed in windows as MX300 G2 Intel display audio.

[image: Sound devices]

Now comes the issue: If I then go into lync and want to see audio devices is gives me the error "we didn't find an audio device which you need for calling" and therefore we are not able to join any meetings.

Now comes the really wired part and workaround: Now if I plug in my webcam "Logitech HD Webcam C310" and the driver install I can now see the audio devices in lync and the speakers play fine from the MX300 G2.

so do anyone have a clue what might be causing this and why the webcam needs to be plugged in before it will play sound and show in lync.

Comment: I have found out that it is a know error at microsoft and now fix wil come.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that lync does not work without a mic plugged in and microsoft does not plan on solving it.

Comment: A citation backing this up would be awesome.